# Why doesn't Chrome work any more?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, fiddler

For "some reason" Google Chrome no longer is able to connect to any website, eventually failing with:

> Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

Other browsers (Firefox, IE10) on the same host are unaffected. According to chrome://chrome/history/, my last successful page get was on 6th November.

Re-running the installer doesn't bring anything up.

**EDIT:**

Wierdly, Chrome does work if I am running [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) (and only if I am), even though it is configured to not use a proxy.

Comment: Have you checked your DNS and/or proxy settings?

Comment: @ChrisF Other browsers are fine, so I'd trust DNS. There is no proxy configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a rogue Chrome process, and rebooting (and not just sleeping) resolved the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by rogue?

Comment: One that showed in task manager, couldn't be killed via task manager, but had no visible windows.

Comment: It was probably from a plugin, but “couldn’t be killed via Task Manager”‽ You mean *End Process* didn’t work? If so, then it was probably from something that hooks into the kernel (which a browser *shouldn’t* be doing), most like the GPU plugin.

Comment: Looks like there was also an issue with Office 2013 causing Windows Installer to have a sulk (which was blocking the reinstall)